# ASPNET MVC trying to access any page requiring authentication causes infinite dialog login loop

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

ASPNET MVC 5 Web application. 
Account/login method has been implemented as a modal dialog.
Login view contains a 'returnurl' method (no need to say how useful it is).

```
$("#modalLoginDiv").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    window.location = '@ViewBag.ReturnUrl';
});
```

But.. Say a user without a valid account happens to load any page requiring authentication: as expected the login method will fire but closing the login modal the 'returnurl' method will fire too, pushing endlessly to the offending page. Modal will reopen and the user won't be able to leave the page.

Is there any nice practice to prevent from this behavior?

Comment: you redirect URL calling your action on controller again and again.

Comment: Best practice is on authenticating successfully/failed on Login action on controller call RedirectToAction and pick values from querystring in URL. Don't return URL back to view.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion Nomi, but in that case the user would be forced to post the login form to the controller, i.e. to insert a fake user and pwd to pass the form validation and send it to the controller: is that what you mean? I just would prefer the user to be able to close the login modal.

Comment: After authentication successful you can directly call the action which is user trying to access[which you specify in querystring], you need to specify authorize attribute on controller as well in order to allow authenticated user to access. In case of authentication failed simply return json false flag and check the response in view in order to show invalid credentials error.

Comment: You could set a global variable on success login or check session cookie and use it in a if statement to wrap around your window redirect. That is if you are dead set on not changing the entire structure of this. Personally I would have the modal call the login method via Ajax and upon callback if login was successful then do the redirect else just display an invalid account message. Leave the modal close event completely out of it. Apologies if I am misunderstanding your question.